# Помогите решить задачу 763

Tags: c++

### Игра с ладьей

На бесконечной вправо и вверх шахматной доске находится ладья. Два игрока передвигают ее по очереди. За один ход разрешено сдвинуть ладью вниз или влево на произвольное (ненулевое) количество клеток так, чтобы ладья не покинула доску. Цель игры – переместить ладью в левый нижний угол, то есть клетку с координатами (1,1). Известно, что оба игрока придерживаются оптимальной стратегии. Игрок №1 ходит первым, при этом он обязан совершить хотя бы один ход. Если первый ход сделать нельзя, то определить победителя также невозможно. Требуется написать программу, которая найдет номер победившего игрока, либо определит, что этого сделать нельзя.

Входные данные
Входной файл INPUT.TXT содержит два натуральных числа, разделенных пробелами: X и Y – координаты ладьи перед первым ходом (X,Y ≤ 10^9).

Выходные данные
В выходной файл OUTPUT.TXT выведите одно число – номер победившего игрока. Если победителя определить невозможно, то следует вывести 0.

Ссылка на оригинал задачи: 
http://acmp.ru/asp/do/index.asp?main=task&id_course=1&id_section=2&id_topic=30&id_problem=174

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Руководствуясь этим условием, можно сделать вывод, что неопределённая ситуация возникает, когда X=Y=1.

Первый игрок побеждает во всех случаях, когда X!=Y или X=1||Y=1

Второй во всех остальных.

```
if (x==1&&y==1){//случай 0} 
if (x!=y){//случай 1} 
if (x==1||y==1){//случай 1}
if (x==y && x!=1){//случай 2}
```

Хочу напомнить, что полное решение остаётся за Вами.

Answer (score -2):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ifstream in("input.txt");
    ofstream out("output.txt");

    int cordX = 0, cordY = 0;
    in >> cordX >> cordY;

    if (cordX <= 1 && cordY <= 1)
    {
        out << "0" << endl;
    }
    else if (cordX == 1 || cordY == 1)
    {
        out << "1" << endl;
    }
    else if (cordX != cordY)
    {
        out << "1" << endl;
    }
    else if (cordX == cordY)
    {
        out << "2" << endl;
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```